# Tap event not working in windows phone 8 by MVVM

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to fire event on tap of listbox item and get the item clicked but the tap event is not firing, please help.

```
<ListBox Margin="0,40,0,0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}" IsHitTestVisible="True" 
         Width="450"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="150" Margin="5"
                  Width="150" Background="Aqua">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <commands:MvxEventToCommand Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the event never get fired? Maybe you were tapping outside the Grid? Listbox item content (the grid in this case) is not stretcing throughout listbox width, it is aligned left by default. To confirm, try to tap at left most area of listbox item and see if the event fired with that.

Assuming the problem is caused by listbox item content not stretching, you can try to set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to fix it :

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: just curious if this actually work/doesn't work. can you confirm?